# Having trouble printing strings in MIPS using (qtSPIM)

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

Basically whenever I print after a certain section of code, in this case the loop,
the output in SPIM's console is either an empty character (looks like a hollow square) or an empty string (several spaces). Need some help figuring out what I'm missing...

```
.data

arrayY: .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5                # array of 5 elements
arrayZ: .word -5, -4, -3, -2, -1                # array of 5 elements
arrayX: .word 20                            # init array 5 elements
var1: .asciiz "X: "
var2: .asciiz ", "

.text
.globl main

main:
    addi $a2, $zero, 5      # init n
    addi $s0, $zero, 2      # init s
    addi $s1 $zero, 1       # init t

    addi $sp, $sp, -12
    sw $s1, 4($sp)          # push to stack
    sw $s0, 0($sp)
    jal AVA



AVA:
    li $v0, 0
    li $v1, 0
    addi $t1, $a2, -1
    addi $t1, $zero, 20
    addi $t0, $zero, 0
    LOOP:
        beq $t0, $t1, exit
        lw $t2, arrayY($t0)
        lw $t3, arrayZ($t0)
        subu $t4, $zero, $t3
        add $t5, $t4, $t2 
        addi $t3, $zero, 2
        mult $t3, $s0
        add $t6, $t3, $s1

        lw $s0, 0($sp)
        lw $s1, 4($sp)
        addi $sp, $sp, 12

        add $t7, $t5, $t6
        sw $t7, arrayX($t0)

        addi $t0, $t0, 4
        j LOOP
    exit:
    addi $t0, $zero, 0
    move $a0, $0
    move $v0, $0
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, var1
    syscall
    LOOP1:
        beq $t0, $t1, exit1
        lw $t2, arrayY($t0)
        move $a0, $t2
        li $v0, 1
        syscall
        addi $t0, $t0, 4
        j LOOP1
    exit1:






    
    li $v0, 10          # exit
    syscall
```

Expected output :

```
X: 12345
```

Actual output :

```
     12345
```

If I print the string earlier in the code, before both loops it prints the string as expected. I'm new to MIPS and thought maybe I had to reset the registers after the loop or something but that didn't do anything differently.

Comment: Run the debugger -- using single step -- and see when the string in question (`var1` having "X:" , for its memory representation) gets trashed, and who (what code) is responsible for that.  It will be at least partially modified in between 2 executing instruction, so find that during single step.  If you didn't know debugging before taking assembly language, now is the time to learn it.  The idea is that with debugging you can become self reliant.  Assembly language has little-to-no protection so if you go out of bounds of one array, you can affect something unintended.

Comment: You can also study your data section before single stepping the first instruction.  Get to know where your data lives (what addresses the various data occupy) so you can recognize those addresses when you see them during single step debugging.

Comment: I just used the debugger in single step and i've found its erased in the second iteration of the loop at the line `sw $t7, arrayX($t0)` I am not sure, however, how to prevent it from being trashed with this information

Comment: Either the code is going to far, accidentally past the end of the array (a logic error) or, the data for the array isn't as large as the code thought it was (also a logic error).  Study your data layout in terms of memory addresses.  (Or maybe you can see it from the assembly source.)

Comment: the first thing i can think of is that the line `addi $t1, $zero, 20`  makes `$t1 = 14` and not 20

Comment: Use the debugger to get an address for each label: `arrayX`, `arrayY`, and `arrayZ`.

Comment: (FYI, 14hex = 20dec, so that's ok.  The debugger can show you values in hex or dec, and in assembly it doesn't know what you'd prefer; there is usually a switch but it will change every item, not just the ones you want to see in dec.)

Comment: forgive me, im new to MIPS, would the address for the label be in the data section or the text section? If its data `address for arrayX = 10000000` , `address for arrayY = 10010000`, and `address for arrayZ = 10010040`

Comment: So, do a table of your data layout -- first column: label name, second column: memory address.  The debugger (some do) may offer you a table like that if you ask for symbols.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  If you don't have a symbol table (MARS has one but I can't find it in QtSpim), you can add an instruction to the beginning of your code, such as `la $t0, arrayZ`.  That will be two instructions worth of code, and if you single stop over both, then you'll have the address of `arrayZ` in $t0.  You can do similar for the others, e.g.`la $t1, arrayY`.

Comment: Ok, there is a menu item in QtSpim: Simulator -> Display Symbols.  It only works for global symbols, so for each label you want it to display you need a line `.globl arrayZ`, for example.  Then the menu item will list the symbols and their addresses.  So, put a `.globl` for each label in the data section, so you can see their addresses.  Using that menu will print a table into the console output section.  (MARS is friendlier with that..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, do this at the beginning:

```
.data
.globl arrayX
.globl arrayY
.globl arrayZ
.globl arrayX
.globl var1
.globl var2

arrayY: .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5                # array of 5 elements
arrayZ: .word -5, -4, -3, -2, -1                # array of 5 elements
arrayX: .word 20                            # init array 5 elements
var1: .asciiz "X: "
var2: .asciiz ", "
```

Then use Simulator menu -> Display Symbols.  Do this menu item before the first single step — these symbols don't move during execution, so get to know your data layout before the first instruction knowing they won't change from there.

Using that information you can track where all your data items are and how big they are, what comes after what, etc...  Then you can make more sense of who is overwriting what, and perhaps why!

Comment: Does QtSPIM or MARS support watchpoints in the debugger?  Break when a given memory location is modified, so you can find out which instruction did it.  If not, yeah manually watching while you single-step works for short programs.  You can let it go quickly the first time, e.g. set a breakpoint somewhere inside a loop and "continue" to step by whole iterations, if the first pass through a loop wasn't the problem.  If you overshoot, figure out where you are and how to stop a bit before that on the next run, then single-step more slowly as you get to the offending instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yeah, If these simulators do have data breakpoints, I don't know of it.  Few toy programs would need this, and even fewer toy programmers would be able to use it as most don't know even debugging basics like view data or single step.  Still, I was also surprised to see how deficient QtSpim's display symbol table is, MARS will show all symbols, global or not with an assemble/build option.  IMHO, the goal here for most coursework is understanding the processor and machine code, not the details of the assembler and/or specific simulator.